# Return control to main file from inside function

Tags: php, scope, return

If I want to return control from an included file to the main file, I can just use `return` in the global scope.

#### Main file

```
<?php

include 'another-file.php';
```

#### Another file

```
<?php

return; // returns control to main file
```

But what can I do if I need to return control from inside a class method?

#### Another file

```
<?php

class Foo {

    function bar() {

        if ( $some_value ) {
            return; // will only return from function, not return whole file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To return it where? `return` returns the control up the stack

Comment: @zerkms to the file that this file was included from

Comment: so? have you tried it? If yes and it doesn't behave as you expected - provide more info

Comment: I've added code examples to clarify the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not possible. You could hack it with throwing exceptions and catching them in your main file, but that's not ideal either. You're basically asking for a type of `goto`.

If you have a need for this, there's probably a better way to solve this :)